# Requirements for STL/CLR Container Elements

Tags: c++-cli

Say I've got a class like the following:

```
public ref class MyClass {};
```

I would like to have a vector of objects of such a class:

```
cliext::vector<MyClass ^> ^myVector;
```

I understand that this is a vector of handles to reference types, isn't it? I mean, this is not a vector of reference types, so I don't need to define any of these requirements:

[Requirements for STL/CLR Container Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385469.aspx)

These requirements would be necessary in case I defined `cliext::vector<MyClass> ^myVector`, because then a copy of each element would be stored in the container and blah blah.

Is all this right? Because I'm getting a `NullReferenceException` when I retrieve an element from the vector. I can see the object is properly constructed, but when I get it back from the vector all its members are undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The STL/CLR library was delivered *very* late, three years after the original promised shipping date.  It was quickly obvious to everybody why, it combined all the disadvantages of the native C++ container classes with the disadvantages of managed memory management.  There is no upside, the library doesn't have a single redeeming value.  Its compatibility with the C++ classes is only a liability, preventing you from doing the right thing.  Review [this page](http://www.voidnish.com/Articles/ShowArticle.aspx?code=StlClrBclComparison) for the horror story.

Do not invest any of your time in making this work, it is utterly wasted effort.  Use the classes in the System::Collections::Generic namespace.

Comment: How about that. My code looks better now with List<MyClass ^>. Many thanks for the tip!